# Is there a way to map row data to new sheets based on a key, to different cells of the same sheet type depending on the key

Tags: excel, vba, mapping, userform

I have a macro that is creating sets of workbooks from multiple different sheets.
For each row within my worksheet table a new workbook is created with certain sheets added to each new workbook depending on a key word in one of the columns on the same row.

I am trying to create a way to map the other row data in a table to certain cells and sheet’s depending on the key.
And also create a way to make the sets of sheets variable and key’s variable.

I can do this with my current code however it’s fixed in code

I want this functionality to be variable through a user form , or even through a mapping table of sorts on my main worksheet. Rather than changing the code each time the sheet names change

As I mentioned I currently can carry out this functionality yet I want my employees to be able to determine where their data sets go and how the sheets are grouped.

The other part is I can’t have references to worksheets as the files are emailed and passed throughout the different areas of the business
***** edit****
The drop downs are determines by a FSO, basically only allowing the user to select from a standard set of templates in a specific folder.

Below is a sample of the variable data I wish to map left column is the Key for the sheet set /TYPE.[Data to be mapped image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k616f.jpg)

Below is the Proposed layout for the grouping of the sets/TYPE, this determines what sheets are to be added into each set or type.
[Set Grouping image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD0cB.jpg)

The output documents are variable however generally look lilke the following, and required to be in any of the cells that the users wishes.
[output data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqpwQ.jpg)

The following is a snippet of the current code that is being used

```
  If worksheetSet = "CB" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX)").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
        ElseIf worksheetSet = "DH" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXXX").Copy After:=targetWb.Sheets(targetWb.Sheets.Count)

 Populate relevant cells in each sheet
For Each sht In targetWb.Sheets
    sht.Range("C1:C2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("AI14:AI15").Value
    sht.Range("L2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("AI16").Value
    sht.Range("L3").Value = wsCxList.Cells(i, "B").Value
    sht.Range("C3").Value = wsCxList.Cells(i, "D").Value
```

I have managed to create the user form with multiple drop downs from target folders etc. this is completed with checkboxes to allow uses to define the set and combine the worksheets into new files with my vba , yet I’m still stuck on the data mapping from my master list (image 1) to the new output files. (Image 3 )

Comment: Pictures and markdown tables say more than a thousand words. Can you please show us what you are trying to do? Preferably with examples of your input and desired output.

Comment: Apologies, will get onto that ASAP. Unfortunately I was away from PC when I put up the OP.

Comment: Updated with examples hope that helps , apologies again.

Answer (score -1):

This will use the mapping table to assign which sheets to copy to each new workbook:

```
Sub copy_sheets()

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim list_control As ListObject, list_sheets As ListObject
Dim r As Range
Dim list_row As Long
Dim arrSheets() As Variant, current_sheet As Variant

'Assign workbook and
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
Set list_control = wbSource.sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Control")
Set list_sheets = wbSource.sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Include_Sheets")

'Loop through rows
For Each r In list_control.ListColumns("Keyword").DataBodyRange
    
    'Check keyword, get list of sheets to copy
    list_row = Application.Match(r, list_sheets.ListColumns("Keyword").DataBodyRange)
    arrSheets = list_sheets.ListRows(list_row).Range
    
    'Add new workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    
    'Loop through array of sheets to add
    For Each current_sheet In arrSheets
        If current_sheet <> r And current_sheet <> "" Then
            wbSource.sheets(current_sheet).Copy After:=wbNew.sheets(wbNew.sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next current_sheet
        
    'Add some code here to save your new workbook
    
Next r

End Sub
```

[image]